# Отобразить столбцы в csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

У меня такая задача

> посчитать суммарное начисление по каждому дому, вывести в файл "Начисления_дома.csv" в формате csv в виде таблицы со столбцами |"№ строки | Улица | № дома | Начислено|.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
file = pd.read_csv('Начисления_абоненты.csv', delimiter = ';', index_col = 0)
list = []
for index, row in file.iterrows():
    # Проверяем, что если в загруженном csv есть столбец который анализируем, 
    df_filtered = file.loc[(file['Улица'] == row['Улица']) & (file['№ дома'] == row['№ дома'])]
    # то продолжаем выполнять действия  
    if df_filtered.empty: continue 
    # Суммируем необходимые столбцы
    list_num = df_filtered['Начислено'].sum()    
    list.append(round(list_num,2))
    file = pd.concat([file, df_filtered.iloc[[0]]], ignore_index=True)
    file.drop(file[(file['Улица'] == row['Улица']) & (file['№ дома'] == row['№ дома'])].index, inplace=True)

    
file.loc[:,'Начислено'] = list
file.loc[:,'№ строки'] = file.index+1
file = file.drop(columns=['Фамилия', '№ Квартиры', 'Тип начисления', 'Предыдущее', 'Текущее']) 

file.to_csv('Начисления_дома.csv', encoding="utf-8-sig", sep=';', index=False)
```

Не понимаю, почему он не выводит название улиц и № дома

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Используйте `groupby` по улице и номеру дома, не занимайтесь самодеятельностью

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте стандартную группировку, примерно так:

```py
df_grouped = df.groupby(['Улица','№ дома'])['Начислено'].sum().reset_index()
```

Comment: А подскажите, это вместо чего-то добавить или вместе с какой-то переменной использовать?

Comment: Это почти вместо всего вашего кода. Ну только у вас датафрейм `file` называется, я просто стандартное `df` написал, вместо него `file` напишите.

Comment: Ну вы короче попробуйте этот код и посмотрите, что получается. Если всё получится, останется только в файл датафрейм вывести.

Comment: Да, работает. Но по заданию надо объединить все улицы и №дома и вывести их сумму, но почему он выводит по отдельности для каждой улицы и дома, сейчас делаю апдейт вопроса

Comment: Да вроде не должно быть такого, на то и группировка. Покажите данные в воспроизводимом виде.

Comment: Добавил данные в вопрос

Comment: Нет, не в виде картинки. В виде картинки я их как должен грузить? )  Я могу только предположить, что у вас там пробелы где-то лишние или буквы где-то русские, где-то английские.

Comment: Попробуйте `print(file['Улица'].unique())` по одному разу улицы напечатает или нет?

Comment: Да, вывод ['Ленина' 'Пушкина']

Comment: А, так вы сохраняйте `df_grouped`, вы же сохраняете `file`. `df_grouped.to_csv(...`

Comment: Господи, и такое бывает. Спасибо огромное!

Comment: Только зря вы мой код из моего ответа в вопрос поместили, это будет запутывать тех, кто будет вопрос читать. Но как это теперь правильно исправить не знаю :)

Comment: Да, исправил на исходное :)